# change the label of the Axes in MSChart VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, fonts, vb.net-2010, mschart

How do I change the label of the Axis in MSChart VB.NET to something like this.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Ssxsd]

In the picture, it shows Volume^3(But the 3 is in the superscript).

Comment: Wow, got a negative vote. Please have the courtesy to comment the answer, or at least say that it's a wrong/stupid question, instead of downvoting the question.

Comment: Can you do something like `Dim volumeTxt As String = "Volume(V³)"` then set your axis label to `volumeTxt `?

Comment: @Baddack I used MSWord to create this formatted text "Volume(V³)". I used your method exactly, but Visual Studio didn't accept, hence I found this other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I got the Answer.

```
Dim UnicodeSuperscriptConversion As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
{
    {"0", ChrW(&H2070)},
    {"1", ChrW(&HB9)},
    {"2", ChrW(&HB2)},
    {"3", ChrW(&HB3)},
    {"4", ChrW(&H2074)},
    {"5", ChrW(&H2075)},
    {"6", ChrW(&H2076)},
    {"7", ChrW(&H2077)},
    {"8", ChrW(&H2078)},
    {"9", ChrW(&H2079)},
    {".", ChrW(&HB7)},
    {"-", ChrW(&H207B)}
}

Dim newString As String = ""
newString += UnicodeSuperscriptConversion(3) '3 for cube.
```